# how to get the JavaScript method called by button?

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML page:

[image]

the button refresh the graph. I want to refresh my graph every 5 seconds automaticly(without user click on this refresh button), so i  I'd like to know how to get the javascript function called by this button, then call it every 5 seconds. Is this the best way to do that?

If it is, how to that?

Comment: Why not just simulate a click?

Comment: Use the [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) event to detect the click, use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) or [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to execute further runs.

Comment: yes, this is graphs in odoo, this page is HTML

Comment: use timer and set it to 5 seconds

Comment: _I'd like to know how to get the javascript function called by this button, then call it every 5 seconds. Is this the best way to do that?_ **Well, yes, it is the best way to do that!**

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    setInterval(function() {

                       $( "#your_refresh_button_id" ).trigger( "click" );

                    }, 5000);

                });
    </script>


<div id="your_refresh_button_id" class="your_refresh_button_class">Your refresh button</div>
```

just replace the id/class of your refresh button

your refresh button automatic perform action after trigger click.
I have checked and it works fine on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

like this

```
function refresh(){
  // put your graph load stuff
}
setInterval(refresh, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval

```
function refreshurpage()
{
//your logic to refresh
}

var count=setInterval(refreshurpage, 5000);
```

and then clear your count when you want this function to stop executing.